# Larger Tabs in Swing

Tags: swing, jtabbedpane

I am working on a touchscreen interface but have lost my bookmarks and cannot seem to find how to make larger JTabbedPane tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/xuanyun/archive/2009/01/change_the_tab.html